# react-native-image-picker launchImageLibrary unable to load photos

Tags: ios, react-native, file-upload, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image using `react-native-image-picker` like this:

```
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';

const handleChoosePhoto = () => {
  launchImageLibrary({}, res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
};
```

Calling `handleChoosePhoto` opens the screen that is shown in the image below. The warning `Unable to Load Photos`. And the error in the console is: `[Picker] Showing picker unavailable UI (reason: unknown) with error: (null)`.

I followed [this doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker) to install `react-native-image-picker`.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker/issues/1405
Maybe it can help you